# how to automatically run bundle install if the gemfile is updated after a git pull/merge?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

I imagine that I should write a git commit hook (post-merge?) that would look at the list of changed files and run bundle install if necessary after I fetch and merge from my git repo.

But after some googling, I figure that either this should exist (couldn't find it!) or there's a good reason not to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a post-merge hook that will fire everytime you pull changes:

```
~/.git/post-merge
```

... and set it up to re-install bundle if needed:

```
bundle check || bundle install
```

Comment: I just used `bundle check || bundle install` in my `./scripts/start`, thanks :) (it would be cool to have it integrated with rerun, shotgun or guard)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`rerun`](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) you can automatically run `bundle install` on Gemfile changes:

```
rerun --no-notify --pattern "Gemfile*" "bundle check || bundle install; true"
```